# Azure Media Services - Live Streaming without Rewind / Timeshift

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am streaming a live event with azure media services. I do not want my users to be able to rewind during the live stream.

Is there a way to disable the rewind / timeshift functionality to achieve that behaviour?

I checked the Documentation but could not find a proper answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-event-cloud-dvr-time-how-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot completely disable it on a live output, but I believe that we support setting the window as low as 1 minute now.

Most clients will want to buffer at least 30 seconds of data anyways, so that is safe to have at least a full minute in the manifest. Otherwise players on slower networks could stall out.

Try setting the archiveWindow length to just "PT1M" (ISO 8601 code for 1 minute)

```
     liveOutputCreate = {
            description: "Optional description when using more than one live output",
            assetName: asset.name,
            archiveWindowLength: "PT1M", // sets a one minute time-shift DVR window. Uses ISO 8601 format string.
        }
```